# Removing something from a list

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove something from a list using a counter but it is not working for me.

```
    int i =0;
    foreach(Rolls rl in rolls)
    {   
        if(rl.getCourseId == courseId && rl.getStudentId == studentId)
        {
            rolls.RemoveAt(i) ;   
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Can anyone see why this might not work. Its gives me a run time exception:

"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: Iterate through the loop backwards

Answer (score 7):

[Jonas explained why this won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943817/65358), but I thought I'd provide another option.

You can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) to remove all matching items in one call:

```
rolls.RemoveAll(rl => rl.getCourseId == courseId && rl.getStudentId == studentId);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify a collection while you're foreach-ing through it. Try using a regular for loop instead (or a while loop):

```
int i = 0;
while(i < myCollection.Count)
{
  if(removeItem)
    myCollection.RemoveAt(i);
  else
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: This won't work either, as your remove items, the indexes change, you'd be removing the wrong item.

Comment: No, that's why you only increment i if you don't remove something.

Comment: Now that you put the example in...yes, this will work, but is awkward.

Comment: Yea, this was the pre-3.0 way...I spent lots of time doing stuff like this so it stuck in my head. :D I'd go with Reed's way nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the collection as you iterate through it with `foreach`.

Try using a for loop like so
`for(int i = 0; i < rolls.Length; i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

Foreach on a collection won't work like that. Try this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < rolls.Count; x++)
{
    if(rolls[x].getCourseId == courseId && rolls[x].getStudentId == studentId)
    {
        rolls.RemoveAt(x);
        --x; //since we removed an item, the index needs to be updated accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't quite work either, because your index would get screwed up. You'd need a --x after your remove.

Answer (score 0):

you should do a loopback

```
for(int i=rolls.Count-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(rolls[i].getCourseId == courseId && rolls[i].getStudentId == studentId)
        rolls.RemoveAt(i)
```